# Как можно выполнить модуль в python использовать переменную для имени модуля

Tags: python

```
 path = 'bot.modules.msg'
 import path as main
 main.main()
```

Comment: importlib.import_module

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

```
import importlib


def main():
    msg = importlib.import_module('bot.modules.msg')
    msg.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```